# Fastest PDF generation in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm attempting to generate some reports dynamically, very simple HTML tables with borders.

I've tried TCPDF and it renders up to 400 rows just fine but anything more than that (about 20 pages) it can't handle it.  DOMPDF can't even do that.

These reports can be thousands of rows.

Any idea on a faster library or a better plan of attack?

Comment: Define "Can't handle it"? If scripts are hitting memory or time limits, there might be other things you can do before switching libraries.

Comment: This is a good point, if it's a memory issue you may try something like this (of course it's dependent on what your host allows): ini_set('memory_limit','128M');

Comment: It opens a new PDF with a header and footer but no content.

Comment: Have you tried setting $diskcache to true in the constructor?

Comment: Are any errors being throw during generation that your server is logging? Missing many details here...

Comment: The latest DOMPDF code has some improvements where resource usage is concerned, though I can't necessarily say it'll help with your problem. I personally haven't tested such a large document. If you can share a sample of your document that might help us as we work on the library's performance.

Answer (score 4):

Try [php-wkhtml2x](https://github.com/mreiferson/php-wkhtmltox) php extension. It uses popular web engine webkit(Chrome and Safari uses that)

Answer (score 2):

I use the FPDF library, the output is fast and resource-efficient. Try it out...
http://www.fpdf.org/

Comment: FPDF is great and very efficient. But.... it cannot handle templates in HTML or something like that.

Comment: FPDF on the linked page mention: `Of course, the generation speed of the document is less than with PDFlib`. Therefore, it certainly is not the fastest as this question asks for...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if these methods are the fastest, but they can certainly handle more than 20 pages.

You could use latex in combination with php:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7870

or Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge
http://www.phphatesme.com/blog/webentwicklung/pdf-erzeugung-mit-dem-zend-framework/

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that depending on the report that PHP is not the right solution you and might consider another alternative language such as perl to accomplish this.  I have no experience with other server-side languages but it is something to keep in mind.  Definitely follow @Pekka's advice and determine the limits and work on adjusting those.

Answer (score 0):

**Fact**
Thousands of rows can be handled by the php.

**My assumption**

Most probably you will be fetching data from db and saving to an array and then you will be looping to write the rows.

This will eat memory.

**My suggestion**

Try to write into the pdf at time of fetching from db. remove the step of storing into an array.

check execution time and memory allocated in php ini.

At last when you generate it , think PDF can handle it or not :-)
surely It will have huge size .

Answer (score 0):

Try [DocRaptor.com](http://www.docraptor.com). It's a web-based app that converts html to pdf. Easy to use.