# Generate PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, zend-pdf, mpdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest PDF generation in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188366/fastest-pdf-generation-in-php)

I've generated a dynamic real-time table and stored it in a variable.

Although I did my homework, I'm bit confused as there are different technologies to achieve this like MPDF, FPDF, Zend_PDF and I am looking for valuable suggestions to choose among these to suit my requirement:

I want an optimized and time-efficient PDF lib which will take the variable which contains the HTML table codes (to generate this table my program it takes lot of time since there are many DB transactions and calculations).

Tutorials for this will be very helpful.

Comment: @AnoopPete: http://cl.ly/image/470Z3y2G321w.  You should review your previous questions and if there is an answer that you deem correct, you should click the checkmark next to that answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dompdf library for generation of pdf files using php.

For more documentation about dompdf library please refer the below url
http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

It has a library function which accepts HTML string as argument and renders the HTML content into pdf file.